# Why Typescript compiler allows class methods without defined Required Parameters

Tags: typescript

See the 'swap' method..
It has a required parameter in the interface definition, which I'm not satisfying in the Class Definition..

[image: code editor]

I would expect my editor to complain about LetterSort not correctly implementing ISwapper?

edit: Also surprising there's no errors doing this which I can only imagine would break (since Typescript should expect this first parameter to be a number that wouldn't have this method)?..

[image: arguments object]

Comment: Compiler will check every call to class methods. In declaration TS doesn't care about parameters existence.

Comment: ok, so you can either declare the function with the correct parameters.. or not declare them at all?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Because source of truth is interface definition.